# Importação de Modulos python

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver

eu estou com um problema com o python.

Eu tenho um arquivo com códigos python trabalhando com selenium, e eu tenho outro arquivo python trabalhando em JSON. Esses dois códigos estão dentro da mesma pasta, para eu importar um arquivo JSON.py para o arquivo Selenium.py

Este é o arquivo JSON.py

```
import json
def json():
    dados = '{'dados_enviar': 'google.com'}'
    data = json.loads(dados['dados_enviar'])
    print(data)
json()
```

Este é o aquivo Selenium.py

```
from JSON import * # meu arquivo JSON.py que está na mesma pasta que o Selenium.py
import json           # biblioteca nativa do python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
elem.send_keys('{}'.data['dados_enviar'])
```

quando eu executo o código ele me retorna o seguinte erro.

```
NameError: global name 'data' is not defined
```

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, cara rodei o seu código em minha IDE, e inicialmente o primeiro erro foi referente ao nome da função que você atribuiu no "JSON.py", o nome `json()` não pode ser utilizado quando se importa a biblioteca json, ao tentar criar uma função com esse nome ele dará erro, visto que essa função já esta deifinida na biblioteca json. Estranho foi seu editor não ter apontado tal problema.

Segunda coisa, você não precisaria necessariamente importar o json nos dois programas, pois se um está importando o outro, não há necessidade.

E perceba que a declaração da variável "dados" possui um erro de sintaxe, se querer que a mesma seja um dicionário, deveria ser da seguinte forma:

```
dados = {'dados_enviar': 'google.com'}
```

EDIT: Quanto ao erro que dá, o mesmo indica que a variavel data não está definida, e isso acontece pois os nomes definidos numa função fazem referência ao módulo em que eles entã odefinidos, e não nos módulos em que eles estão sendo importados, tenho uma sugestão para corrigir isso, que seria:

JSON.py:

```
import json
def worker():
    dados = {'dados_enviar': 'google.com'}
    data = json.loads(dados['dados_enviar'])
    return data
```

Selenium.py:

```
from JSON import * 
import json           
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

data = worker()   #Fazendo isso, você estancia a variavel no módulo local, recebendo o valor retornado pelo import

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
elem.send_keys('{}'.data['dados_enviar'])
```

Comment: Eu tinha colocado (dados =  '{"processo": "google.com"}'  ), editei o código como você disse mas ele retorna um erro para mim (  TypeError: expected string or buffer  )

Comment: eu editei o nome da função, coloquei (  def worker():   ), continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: editei a pergunta a fim de tentar resolver o que queres, veja se foi coerente, e se funcionou!

Comment: OOOWW obrigado cara ajudou muito!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Quando você define uma variável em uma função, ela só é acessível **nessa função**. Portanto, o `data` definido em `def json()` não está disponível em no contexto do seu `Selenium.py`.

Para disponibilizar informações para outras funções, você as tem que passar através de uma instrução de retorno dentro da função, possivelmente atribuindo-a a uma variável. Assim você poderá chamar essa variável retornada que está "carregada" com os dados que vieram do seu json.

```
import json
def json():
    dados = '{'dados_enviar': 'google.com'}'
    data = json.loads(dados['dados_enviar'])
    print(data)
    return data
json()
```

Comment: então, eu fiz isso que você me sugeriu, ele me retornou error ( NameError: name 'data' is not defined )

Comment: Sim, você tem que declarar ela como variável global. Dá uma lida nisso. É bem fácil de entender e aplicar. Ali coloquei só um direcionamento